# how to add iiwa joint torque sensor in drake

Tags: sensors, drake, torque

I want to use iiwa's joint torque feedback data in my controller's input.

But I didn't find API to get joint torque data.

Which API should I use?

`get_reaction_forces_output_port.` or `get_generalized_contact_forces_output_port`?

Answer (score 1):

The iiwa API makes three torque values available: commanded, measured, and external.  In the `manipulation_station` simulation, we take commanded to be the value of the input port, measured to be the same (assuming ideal torque tracking), and external to be the value from the `get_generalized_contact_forces_output_port` -- since contact forces are the only source of external torques.

You can see that code [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/53571e1d65d1716d8b4b72ae8d3571ee89fa36cf/examples/manipulation_station/manipulation_station.cc#L657-L658) and [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/53571e1d65d1716d8b4b72ae8d3571ee89fa36cf/examples/manipulation_station/manipulation_station.cc#L690-L692).